# Haskell: No instance for (Eq Movimento) arising from a use of `myhasLoops'

Tags: haskell

```
data Movimento = Norte | Sul | Este | Oeste
                deriving Show

myhasLoops :: Eq Movimento => (Int,Int) -> [Movimento] -> Bool
myhasLoops (x,y) (h:t) | auxxx (x,y) (h:t) 0 == 0 = True
                       | otherwise = False

auxxx :: Eq Movimento => (Int,Int) -> [Movimento] -> Int -> Int
auxxx (x,y) (h:t) acc | h == Norte = 1 + auxxx (x,y) t (acc+1)
                      | h == Sul = (-1) + auxxx (x,y) t (acc-1)
                      | h == Este = 1 + auxxx (x,y) t (acc+1)
                      | h == Oeste = (-1) + auxxx (x,y) t (acc-1)
                      | otherwise = acc
```

With myhasLoops (1,2) [Norte, Sul] results in:

```
<interactive>:125:1: error:                                                                                                                                                 
* No instance for (Eq Movimento) arising from a use of `myhasLoops'                                                                                                     
* In the expression: myhasLoops (1, 2) [Norte, Sul]                                                                                                                       
In an equation for `it': it = myhasLoops (1, 2) [Norte, Sul]
```

Why is this error happening? :/

I tried a lot of alternatives but i can't figure out what's ocurring :(

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting that error rather than a different one - but no matter, `Eq Movimento` doesn't make any sense because `Movimento` is an actual type, not a type variable. You should remove this part of both type signatures and just change the `deriving Show` in `Movimento`'s definition to `deriving (Show, Eq)`

Comment: (actually you wouldn't need `Movimento` to have an `Eq` instance if you rewrote `auxxx` to use pattern matching rather than equality checks)